# How to open a file and remove the last line?

Tags: php, fopen, fgets, fwrite

I am looking to open up a file, grab the last line in the file where the line = "?>", which is the closing tag for a php document.  Than I am wanting to append data into it and add back in the "?>" to the very last line.

I've been trying a few approaches, but I'm not having any luck.

Here's what I got so far, as I am reading from a zip file.  Though I know this is all wrong, just needing some help with this please...

```
// Open for reading is all we can do with zips and is all we need.
if (zip_entry_open($zipOpen, $zipFile, "r"))
{
    $fstream = zip_entry_read($zipFile, zip_entry_filesize($zipFile));
    // Strip out any php tags from here.  A Bit weak, but we can improve this later.
    $fstream = str_replace(array('?>', '<?php', '<?'), '', $fstream) . '?>';

    $fp = fopen($curr_lang_file, 'r+');

    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $output = fgets($fp, 16384);
        if (trim($output) == '?>')
            break;
    }

    fclose($fp);
    file_put_contents($curr_lang_file, $fstream, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

`$curr_lang_file` is a filepath string to the actual file that needs to have the fstream appended to it, but after we remove the last line that equals '?>'

Ok, I actually made a few changes, and it seems to work, BUT it now copies the data in there twice... arggg, so each line in the file is now in there 2 times :(

Ok, removed the fwrite, though now it is appending it at the bottom, just below the ?>

OMG, I just need everything up to the last line, isn't there a way to do this???  I don't need "?>"

Comment: Why do u need to insert the code at the last line, if the code doesn't depend on the order of the execution you better off insert after <?php  tag. Your approach doesn't look good to me.

Comment: Well I assume it would be best to add it at the end of the file... hmm

Answer (score 2):

A simple way with the file on the filesystem:

```
<?php

$path = "file.txt";
$content = file($path); // Parse file into an array by newline
$data = array_pop($content);

if (trim($data) == '?>') {
    $content[] = 'echo "... again";';
    $content[] = "\n$data";
    file_put_contents($path, implode($content));
}
```

Which does..

```
$ cat file.txt 
<?php
echo 'Hello world';
?>
$ php test.php 
$ cat file.txt 
<?php
echo 'Hello world';
echo "... again";
?>
```

Comment: The lines in the array returned by `file` do still contain the line break character sequence!

Comment: This code doesn't work. [Here is a more complete answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624664/simple-php-function-to-remove-the-last-line-from-text-file-not-working/19624799#19624799).

Comment: @geomagas It has been completed now

Answer (score 0):

It's copying each line twice because of your line that says:

```
 @fwrite($fp, $output);
```

You're just reading the file to find the end tag, there's no need to write the line you've read as you read.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I need to get rid of the last line where the line = "?>" unless there is a better way to do this...?

Comment: Well, I took that line out, and now it's not removing "?>" at all :(

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new `<? YOUR CODE ?>` after the last line...

Or if you have the new PHP code to add in `$code` this could be done with a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

`$output = preg_replace('\?>','?>'.$code,$output)`

Comment: I'm confused, what does this do exactly?  Can you show me a better example perhaps, using the code I have above?  It's just that $fstream can have php tags in it also, which I believe they should be stripped out too??

Comment: The `$fstream` = the code I need placed within the php file either after `"<?php"` or before `"?>"`, doesn't matter I suppose.  But I'd prefer it be just before `"?>"`.  Am I closing the file too soon, should I be writing to it differently?  OMG, I'm so lost here, I feel brain-dead!

Comment: Ok, thanks, I am using `"\n" . '<?' .  MY CODE .  '?>'`, however, just wondering can I use `<?php` instead of `<?`, or can it not be in there twice in a php document?  I feel stupid here as I'm still learning everything...

Comment: I can't understand how preg_replace works, even after reading the php manual on it.  Just doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @sologhost: You can have as many <?php ?> blocks as you want in a file. There's no practical limit, other than how ugly and unreadable  the code can get if you sprinkle a few million or billion of them around

Comment: @osama: This will append the code to EVERY ?> tag within the file. That's ok in this case, if sologhost only has the one closing tag, but otherwise you're going to end up with a huge spaghetti file.