# Simple PHP function to remove the last line from text file not working

Tags: php, file

I have a text file named `test` with only 2 lines:

```
1
2
```

I want to be able to remove the last line from the file so I use the following function:

```
<?php

$file = file('test.txt');
array_pop($file);
file_put_contents(implode($file));

?>
```

For some reason, this does nothing and the file still has the exact lines..am I missing something here?

Comment: where do you write it back?

Comment: edited it and still the same

Comment: Where do you specify the filename to be written?

Comment: It should be `file_put_contents('test.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $file))` instead.

Comment: yup that was the mistake...i don't know all the examples do it like this without specifying the file to be written!

Comment: Where are those examples? I'd really like to see them!

Comment: would you posts it as answer to mark the question as answered?

Comment: @geomagas here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711261/how-to-open-a-file-and-remove-the-last-line http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/175739-remove-last-line-in-a-file-phpstore-all-lines-except-the-last-one/ http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch18_16.htm

Comment: You should really start using the [PHP documentation/API](http://php.net/docs.php)...

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: Left a comment on the SO one. The other two don't even bother saving the file back! Listen to Horse SMith though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**file**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function only returns you the contents of a file (as an array) - and whatever you do with that array, only changes the array, not the file. To persist the changes, write the contents back to the file:

```
$filename = 'test.txt';
$arr = file($filename);
if ($arr === false) {
  die('Failed to read ' . $filename);
}
array_pop($arr);
file_put_contents($filename, implode(PHP_EOL, $arr));
```